# Validating int data from database

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

The following code illustrate the use of the class model: `Student`

```
public class Student: IAbstract
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    //Some methods
}
```

This the method `index()` from `StudentController`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new List<Student>();

    var objStudent = new Student();
    var cmd = new SqlBuilder();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT StudentID, FirstName, Age FROM Students";
    var data = objStudent.Select(cmd);

    foreach (DataRow item in data.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        model.Add(new Student
        {
            StudentID = Convert.ToInt32(item["StudentID"]),
            FirstName = item["FirstName"].ToString(),
            Age = item.IsNull("Age")?0:Convert.ToInt32(item["Age"]) //Here
        });
    }

    return View("Index", model);
}
```

As you can see I have to check if "Age" is null because in my db(for testing purposes) some students have not age set. But I do not want to set `Age` to `0` for the view, so which is the best way to show a "void" cell in the view instead of a `0`?.

Part of the view code:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StudentID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
            </th>

            <th></th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.StudentID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.StudentID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.StudentID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `Age` to be a nullable int:

```
public int? Age { get; set; }
```

Then the default value would be nothing, not 0.

Your parsing logic could then look like:

```
Age = item.IsNull("Age") ? null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(item["Age"]) //Here
```

Comment: I thought about it, but I get the following error `Error 3 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'int' `

Comment: whoops, yep, you need to cast the right hand side to `int?`, to make the conditional operation valid.  See my edit.